# Python input issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

```
name_list = []
command_list = ["Add" ,"Help"]

def start():
 input("Hello please type in a command : ")

start()

if (input == "help" or "Help"):
    print("Here are the following commands for this program : ")
    i = 0
    for i in command_list :
       print("'" + i + "'")
    start()


if (input == "Add" or "add" ):
 name = input("Insert name please : ")
 print("Welcome " + name)
 name_list.append(name)
```

*So this code is causing me a bit of trouble , upon starting the code everything works fine it asks me to type in a command as it should , and if i type in 'help' it does exactly what its supposed to do, which is list all the commands, after that its supposed to reset via the start() command and once again ask me to input a command , however this time no matter what i write it activates this block of code:*

```
 if (input == "Add" or "add" ):
 name = input("Insert name please : ")
 print("Welcome " + name)
 name_list.append(name)
```

Can someone please help me fix this and or explain why this is happening??

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: you probably need a while loop somewhere

Comment: @AshishAcharya a while loop for what?

Comment: First your `if` statements will always be true. This is not the situation you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a while loop here, also `repr(i)` more efficient than `"'" + i + "'"`:

```
name_list = []
command_list = ["Add" ,"Help"]

def start():
    return input("Hello please type in a command : ")

a=start()

while a.lower()=='help':
    print("Here are the following commands for this program : ")
    i = 0
    for i in command_list :
       print(repr(i))
    a=start()


if a.lower()=='add':
 name = input("Insert name please : ")
 print("Welcome " + name)
 name_list.append(name)
else:
 print('invalid input')
```

Example output:

```
Hello please type in a command : help
Here are the following commands for this program : 
'Add'
'Help'
Hello please type in a command : Help
Here are the following commands for this program : 
'Add'
'Help'
Hello please type in a command : Add
Insert name please : Bob
Welcome Bob
```

and also:

```
print(name_list)
```

Returns:

```
['Bob']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues. Here's a version that works.

```
name_list = []
command_list = ["Add", "Help"]


def start():
    return input("Hello please type in a command : ")


name = ""

while not name:
    command = start()

    if (command.lower() == "add"):
        name = input("Insert name please : ")
        print("Welcome " + name)
        name_list.append(name)

    # printing help for everything except add
    else:
        print("Here are the following commands for this program : ")
        i = 0
        for i in command_list:
            print(repr(i))
```

Comment: also `repr(i)` more efficient than `"'" + i + "'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (input == "help" or "Help"):
    print("Here are the following commands for this program : ")
    i = 0
    for i in command_list :
       print("'" + i + "'")
    start()  # <--- your call to start() function does not reset where the interpreter left off reading you code.
```

Python interpreter simply reads each one of your lines and does something with it. In your if statement, the line `start()` is called, it ask for an user input and returns None. Then this if statement is complete, then the next line read is as you described:

```
if (input == "Add" or "add" ):
 name = input("Insert name please : ")
 print("Welcome " + name)
 name_list.append(name)
```

Solution to your question:

```
name_list = []
command_list = ["Add" ,"Help"]

def start():
 input("Hello please type in a command : ")
while True:
   start()

   if (input == "help" or "Help"):
       print("Here are the following commands for this program : ")
       i = 0
       for i in command_list :
          repr(i)

   if (input == "Add" or "add" ):
    name = input("Insert name please : ")
    print("Welcome " + name)
    name_list.append(name)

   if input == "something for break condition":
       break
```

Comment: also `repr(i)` more efficient than `"'" + i + "'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
name_list = []
command_list = ["Add" ,"Help"]

def start():
 inpt =  input("Hello please type in a command : ")
 if (inpt == "help" or inpt == "Help"):
    print("Here are the following commands for this program : ")
    print(command_list)
    start()
 elif (inpt == "Add" or inpt == "add" ):
     name = input("Insert name please : ")
     print("Welcome " + name)
     name_list.append(name)
     yn = input("Do you want to add another person? ")
     if yn in ['y','Y','yes','Yes','YES']:
         start()
     else: 
         print ("Quitting!! all the people entered are")
         print(name_list)
         return (None)

 else:
     print("Please type 'help' for help")
     start()
```